# MKL init when static linking MKL

Tags: intel-mkl, intel-ipp

I know that when you statically link against IPP one should call ippInit() before using any IPP's function.
Do you have to do the same when linking statically against MKL ? If so what is the function name to init MKL ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't need to call a function like that to *initialize* MKL. Simply including the header, and then calling the MKL function(s) that you require should be enough.

If you're still struggling to get the static linking to work correctly, look [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor) to get the compiler and linker to work correctly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

regarding to IPP - actually, since the last two versions, you don't need to call IppInit function. IPP dispatches the code automatically.